# Cut Font Awesome symbol in half?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How could one cut a Font Awesome symbol in half? I don't mean make it half width, I mean actually cut it in half. For example, if I wanted a half circle (`fa-circle`).

Preferably this would work for all percentages, not just 50%, meaning I could cut symbols in quarters, fifths, tenths, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
i.fa {
  position: relative;
}

i.fa:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2232/

Comment: I like this method the most, it's much easier to understand IMO.

Comment: This is the answer I will go with. Here's an updated version with specifically what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/busterroni/GCu2D/2235/. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

**HTML**

`<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

**CSS**

```
i {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 16px, 8px, 0px);
}
```

16px is the font-size of the icon, and 8px is half of the font-size.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/QOvEwJ)

Comment: Why downvote? This is one possible solution to your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I upvoted to balance it out. Thanks for your solution, I'm currently experimenting.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy I didn't downvote, but a quick MDN search shows that `clip` property is deprecated in CSS. So whoever voted, might be signalling that you shouldn't use it. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

Comment: This answer works, and dividing the second argument of `rect` by how much you want (e.g. `16/3` for a third of a circle) allows it to work for all percentages. However, since it's deprecated, I think I will look for another solution.

Comment: Try experimenting with the `clip-path` property. Please see my updated demo for example usage: https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/QOvEwJ

And thank you @NisargShah for pointing out that the `clip` property has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of doing so would be to overlay a white box on top of the Font Awesome icon.

In the snippet below, I am overlaying the `fa-stop` icon (i.e. `\f04d`) on top of the `fa-circle` icon.

Since I have given the `right` value of `-7px` it covers almost half of the circle, but you can tweak that value to suit your requirement.

```css
.fa-overlay{
  position: relative;
}

.fa-overlay:after {
  content: "\f04d";
  position: absolute;
  right:-7px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa fa-circle fa-overlay"></span>
```

Comment: Would there be a way to automatically calculate how much to move the `fa-stop` based on what percent of the symbol should be covered, or would it be necessary to manually calculate it?

Comment: @busterroni I can't think of anything that does that.

Comment: Use `right:-0.5em;`.  But only use this if you always putting your icon on a white background.

Answer (score 0):

CSS inset box shadow. You'll need to know the pixel size bcs I don't think % is accepted. See example below. Note your background can be an image.

```css
div{
  height:48px;
  width:48px;
  background:blue;
  box-shadow: inset 24px 0px 0px 0px       rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
}
```

```html
<div>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following as per your requirement.

```
<i class="fa fa-circle" style="width: 25%; overflow: hidden;"></i>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-flip-horizontal" style="width: 25%; overflow: hidden;"></i>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-circle" style="height: 25%; overflow: hidden;"></i>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-flip-vertical" style="height: 25%; overflow: hidden;"></i>
```

Comment: Use: `height:0.5em` otherwise it's `25%` of the container, which could be useless.